# What is the difference between accuracy_score and clf.score in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, floating-accuracy

```py
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=500, n_features=2, centers=2, random_state=34)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print(clf.score(X_test, y_test) == accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

The output of the above code is:

```
True
```

I don't know the difference between them, can someone tell me?

---

**Edit:** The [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/base.py#L625) of the `score` function is:

```py
def score(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
    """
    Return the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.
    In multi-label classification, this is the subset accuracy
    which is a harsh metric since you require for each sample that
    each label set be correctly predicted.
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)
        Test samples.
    y : array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
        True labels for `X`.
    sample_weight : array-like of shape (n_samples,), default=None
        Sample weights.
    Returns
    -------
    score : float
        Mean accuracy of ``self.predict(X)`` wrt. `y`.
    """
    from .metrics import accuracy_score

    return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

i.e., the `score` function is implemented with `accuracy_score` function, so these two functions are the same?

Answer (score 1):

`clf.score()` is actually for the [SVC class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html), and it returns the mean accuracy on the given data and labels.

[`accuracy_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) on the other hand returns a fraction of instances where classification was done correctly. For example, if you pass-in 10 items for classification, and say 7 of them are classified correctly (whatever is the clsss - True / False, Multiclass), its return value will be `0.7`. You can set a flag normalize to `False` and then it will return just an integer of how many instances were classified correctly.

Comment: I still don't know what is the mean accuracy in clf.score(), I only have one test set.

Comment: Are clf.score and accuracy_score the same in a binary classification scenario?

Comment: @Lancdorr, well not always.`clf.score()` would depend on the metrics you use such as MSE, etc. `accuracy_score` is simply matching two lists if you will - [a, b, c.. ] to [a', b', c'], each of the item could be a list in itself. I should mention `clf.score()` would also depend on the `class_weight` for SVC.  So you could get them to be the same in some instances, they are not doing the same things. This is also justified by their parameters, and environment. You can use `accuracy_score` on any two vectors or vectors of vectors or maybe tensors, but `model.score()` needs more context - a model!

Comment: I modified my question, I put the source code of the `score` function in the question, could you take a look again?

Comment: I don't see how that changes anything. In `score()` prediction is computed + `accuracy_score()` is calculated, whereas in the latter `only accuracy_score()` is computed - and this is the difference. I am sorry but I don't think there is more to it. If you could let me know what is causing you to know the difference, or how you intend to use one or the other based on what they do, I might be able to add a comment.

Comment: From the underlying implementation of `score()`, it can be seen that the results returned by these two functions are the same, and the number of lines of code required to use the `score()` function is less, so do you recommend using `score()`?

Comment: With default parameters, yes, they will be same. If your concern is if using score() is a right thing, I would say-Yes, for the code and classifier you are showing. Number of lines will be less with `score()`, but computation is exactly same behind the scene. (In general, LOC should not be a concern unless one got some special circumstances). Hope this helps.